where the "-O2" option in cmake come from and how to remove it?
I'm trying to rebuild a rpm package perl-BSSolv from source on opensuse 15.5 and debug with the new build package. I need to remove the optimization option -O2 or -O3 before I start to build debuginfo package. Here is what I tried:
I change lines in CMakeLists.txt as below:
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS     "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -Wall")
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O2")
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g -O0")
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG     "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g3 -O0")

to
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS      -Wall")
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELEASE "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -O0")
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_RELWITHDEBINFO "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g -O0")
set (CMAKE_C_FLAGS_DEBUG     "${CMAKE_C_FLAGS} -g3 -O0")

then run rpmbuild -ba SPEC/xxx.spec to rebuild the package and reinstall packages with command below:
rpm -ivh --replacepkgs --replacefiles RPMS/x86_64/xxx-*.rpm

but when I installed the new packages and try to debug with gdb, there is still some unexpected results like vars are optimized and unexpected jump in code
Run command below:
readelf --debug-dump=info FILE_I_BUILD.so|grep  "DW_AT_producer"

I can see output like:
   <3592>   DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0x1d): GNU AS 2.43.1
    <35a5>   DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0x655): GNU C11 7.5.0 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -O2 -fwrapv -fno-strict-aliasing -fstack-protector-strong -fmessage-length=0 -fstack-protector-strong -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables -fstack-clash-protection -fPIC
    <2e83f>   DW_AT_producer    : (indirect string, offset: 0xb77b): GNU C11 7.5.0 -m64 -mtune=generic -march=x86-64 -g -g -O2 -O2 -O0 -fmessage-length=0 -fPIC -fmessage-length=0 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables


The "-O2" option still exists, seems my settings in CMakeLists.txt did not change the optimization options when build the package.
Where did this "-O2" option from and how can I remove it?

Are you sure you aren't seeing modules loaded from some static library?

-O0 cancels all other -O before it.

@TimRoberts I'm not sure what you mean. what I can tell you is that this packages contains only one .so file. and no other binary file. I can set break point in functions in the source and gdb successfully break where I set break point.

@n.m.couldbeanAI Sure. Line 2 of the output shows that the optimization level is 2 not 0 as I expect. And the command "readelf --debug-dump=info FILE_I_BUILD.so|grep  "DW_AT_producer"" I used here was a way to check which flags are used when this binary is build, but I'm not sure what's the difference between those lines.

I'm not sure what this line refers to exactly either. I would recommend running a verbose build and looking all the actual flags.

Your .so clearly includes multiple object files, otherwise there wouldn't be multiple signatures.  I'm suggesting that some of those signatures are from objects from other libraries, like libc, maybe?

"Where did this "-O2" option from and how can I remove it?" - The option is set somewhere in the project itself. This setting could be in form of changing CMake variable (e.g. CMAKE_C_FLAGS), in form of setting of some property (e.g. COMPILE_OPTIONS) or in form of calling some command (e.g. target_compile_options), which effectively sets a property. You need to find out the exact way in the project, and modify corresponding variable or property for suppress that setting.

I think I found the way to meet my needs.

Since the build host is opensuse, the first thing to remove optimize options is to modify /usr/lib/rpm/rpmrc，find lines related to your build host arch and modify the flags as below:

optflags: x86_64 -O0 -g -m64 -fmessage-length=0 -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fstack-protector -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-unwind-tables
optflags: amd64 -O0 -g


I noticed that while building the output shows that an Makefile.PL was run before make so I modified spec file. Add OPTIMIZE="-g3 -O0" at the end of lineperl Makefile.PL --bundled-libsolv

After these 2 steps, you can see the optimization level is set to 0.
But where to find the default option for perl module ExUtils::MakerMaker is sitll unknown
